# Unable to activate mobile account

Tags: macos, osx-server, open-directory

I am in a dead end.

I am trying to settup mobile account on 10.8 Server, with 10.8 clients.

So far, I got my Open Directory seted up server.name.private
I created a new user in the Users tab, named test
The Home Folder is setted up for my Homes folder, which is on a secondary hard drive.
This file is shared with File Sharing, and have read/write permission for the group of my user.
If I check the folder permission in the Finder, it is strange, but I don't know how to clean them. Each group is there two times, and they have Custom privilege

With Workgroup Manager, I selected my user, went to the Preferences tab, and setted up the Mobility section.
The options for Account Creation are Manage: Always, Account Expiry are Manage: Never and under Rules, Home Sync, I selected Once.

On the client side, I activated the mobile account option, and entered the Open Directory adress.
And when I log in, I put my info test/password, and the message You are unable to log in to the user account "test" at this time. Logging in to the account failed because an error occured.

And here is the log from the server

```
CFPreferences: user home directory for user kCFPreferencesCurrentUser at /var/teamsserver is unavailable. User domains will be volatile
```

Does someone have a clue for me?

Thanks!

Comment: That message is going to be tough to search since I get it even on machines that never have seen a server. I've tried to stay as far away from Workgroup manager on 10.8 and use Profile Manager and the server App as much as possible. Have you tried making a new user there?

Comment: That error message has nothing to do with mobile accounts, it has to do with the wiki&blog service on the server (see [http://codedmemes.com/lib/firing-up-os-x-server/](http://codedmemes.com/lib/firing-up-os-x-server/)). Is there anything relevant in the client's system.log when you try to log in? Also, can you clarify the exact steps you used to set up the user's home folder?

Comment: After checking the you posted, I realized that I don't have a TeamsServer System Records, or the folder _/var/teamsserver_

[And here is a little bit more code from the system.log after I tried to connect](http://d.pr/f/q4zc)

Comment: I have no clue how all this works… I just seted up the Profile Manager inside Server App, and the mobility account wasn't active… I tried to create a new account and configure it there, but got the same error…

Answer (score 1):

NB: the account home folder at /var/teamsserver *is misspelled* by apple. Check it out carefully - it only has one "s". Create a properly spelled folder in var, then run chown to make sure it's owned by teamsserver and you'll be good to go.